# How to remove dynamic multidimensional array key if that array doesn't have values. using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional array called $array and `$array1`, the keys and values are dynamic, i am able to find the `array_diff()` of `$array` and `$array1` and i want to print the array keys as table column name and array values as table values. The real problem am facing is that i am not able to omit the column which doesn't have values.  Here i am giving sample code which have hard coded array keys and values.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);
$array[0] = array("key1" => "valueNew", "key2" => "Array2", "key3" => "value3", "key4" => "value4");
$array[1] = array("key1" => "valuetwo", "key2" => "Array2", "key3" => "value3", "key4" => "value4");
$array[2] = array("key1" => "valueThree", "key2" => "Array2", "key3" => "value3", "key4" => "value4");

$array1[0] = array("key1" => "Array1", "key2" => "Array2", "key3" => "Array3", "key4" => "Array4");
$array1[1] = array("key1" => "Array1", "key2" => "Array2", "key3" => "Array3", "key4" => "Array4");
$array1[2] = array("key1" => "Array1", "key2" => "Array2", "key3" => "Array3", "key4" => "Array4");


for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
$implode[$i]=array_diff($array[$i],$array1[$i]);

}
$arrayKeys=array_keys($array[0]);

?>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
  <?php
  for($i=0;$i<count($arrayKeys);$i++){
  ?>
    <th scope="col"><?php echo $arrayKeys[$i]; ?></th>
    <?php
  }
    ?>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php
  for($i=0;$i<count($arrayKeys);$i++)
  {
    ?>
    <td><?php for($j=0;$j<count($implode);$j++)
    {
        echo $implode[$j][$arrayKeys[$i]]."<br>"; 
    } ?></td>
        <?php
  }
    ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *The real problem am facing is that i am not able to omit the column which doesn't have values.* `$ar = array_filter($ar);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) functions.

Try below code instead of your for loop.

```
$res = array_map(function($a,$b){
  return [array_filter(array_diff($a,$b))];
},$array,$array1);
```